# Ajax / PHP code causes 404 error

Tags: php, ajax

I'm running a JavaScript function which I know is being ran and is working, but it seems like the Ajax part isn't working.

**JavaScript:**

```
socket.on('chat-message', function(msg){
   $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
   $.post("test.php", {message: msg});
});
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    mkdir($message);
?>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I seem to be getting a 404 error on the PHP file which doesn't make sense since the file is in the same directory as the `index.html` file

> D:\xampp\htdocs\Collabs\Examples\Chat

[image: PICTURE]

Comment: hard to say, what's being passed in the input? [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) if it doesn't resemble `mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);` then something's not right.

Comment: It's just a message being sent such as 'test'. I want the directory to just be created at the php file's path hence the fact I didn't add the pathing

Comment: read the manual then http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's not a problem with mkdir. I just tried it with other examples. It's got to be a problem with my ajax

Comment: Is test.php receiving the ajax request?

Comment: @EternalHour Just posted an edit (:

Comment: What's running your web server on port 3000? It will need to support PHP. Looks like it's not even serving the PHP file

Comment: test.php is located in the base directory? Your web server listens on port 3000 rather than 80?

Comment: It seems your `php` path is not correct. Use `http://localhost/test.php`

Comment: I just realized that it was hosted on port 3000... lol I just changed it to port 80 but I'm not sure where my file needs to be in order the be ran. I currently have it in the same path as the server/html script

Comment: @Manwal not everyone runs their web server on port 80

Comment: Solved your problem?

Comment: Afraid not @SanjayKumarNS

Comment: Can you add an echo like this.
echo mkdir($message);

Comment: I'm having trouble even accessing the file. It seems I have a problem with the directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP and nodejs code are 2 separate web servers, running on different ports. Your PHP script is likely to be running on apache on port 80 and the node.js on port 3000.

Change the ajax post request to port 80:

```
$.post("http://localhost/test.php", {message: msg});
```